# How to write on other values placed after the operators case?

Tags: java, processing, control-p5

Good afternoon, I am using the switch construction, but I don’t know how to write correctly for other values after the case operators.

In the DisplayData code, in the switch construction, I assign a command number to the fields, for example: Vin = cp5.addTextlabel, so that later, when connecting via a com port, display or change the data by sending this command "60",123 in the Vin = cp5.addTextlabel field.

Only works in (minutess = cp5.addButton) - 10, (Vin = cp5.addTextlabel) - 60,
(inputPULI = cp5.addNumberbox) - 40, (inputNapryzenieKV = cp5.addNumberbox) - 70

The main error is below (function "setText (String)" is undefined. See screenshot.

How do I fix this for variables and write it correctly?

ImageButton button;

RadioButton CheckBoxuvum; [Documentation](http://www.sojamo.com/libraries/controlP5/reference/controlP5/RadioButton.html)

CheckBox P4; [Documentation](http://www.sojamo.com/libraries/controlP5/reference/controlP5/CheckBox.html)

See the GUI file!

A task:

ImageButton (button) - 20, the goal is to get a picture change in the window by sending a command through a terminal or microcontroller.

P4 = cp5.addCheckBox - 30 CHECK, the goal is to get a change in the state of the checkbox on and off in the window by sending a command through a terminal or microcontroller.

CheckBoxuvum = cp5.addRadioButton - 50 +/-, the goal is to get a change in the state of the checkbox on and off (+/-) in the window by sending a command through a terminal or microcontroller.

In the Displaydata code, I marked this with a question.

In the future, I plan to send commands from the terminal via the com port to receive a change in the state of the data in the window for these values.

Screenshot of errors:
[image]

I will have to upload all the test project files so you can test this.

Com_Interface1:

```
import processing.serial.*;
import controlP5.*;
ControlP5 cp5;
DropdownList serialPortsList;

Serial serialPort;
final int BAUD_RATE = 115200;

char parity = 'N';
int dataBits = 8;
float stopBits = 1.0;

public void setup() {
  size(700, 420, JAVA2D);
  surface.setTitle("TEST");
  surface.setResizable(false);
  setupUI();
  smooth();
  frameRate(30);
  writeOutgioing[lengthmas-1]=1; 
  String[] portNames = Serial.list();
  //serialPort.clear(); // Why does not it work?
  for (int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++) serialPortsList.addItem(portNames[i], i);
}
public void toplug (int theValue) { // Start button on click sends a commad 1.
  println("Button click events: "+theValue);
  strata =!strata;
  if (!strata) {
    connection.setLabel("Пуск");
  } else {
    connection.setLabel("СТОП");
    serialports((int)serialPortsList.getValue());
    writeOutgioing[0]=1;
    writeOut();
  }
}
public void serialports(int theValue) {
  try {
    serialPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[theValue], BAUD_RATE, parity, dataBits, stopBits);
    serialPort.bufferUntil('\n');

    println("COM connected: "+ Serial.list()[theValue] );
    /*Send.unlock();
     connection.unlock();*/    //locking buttons in applications if not connected via rs-232.
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error opening serial port" + Serial.list()[theValue]);
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Displaydata:

```
    void Displaydata() {

  switch(readIncome[0]) {
  case 10:
    minutess.setCaptionLabel(readIncome[1]+" Мин1.");
    min1=readIncome[1];
    break;
  case 20:
    // What to write?
    // label(readIncome[1]+" Мин."); // ImageButton
    // min=readIncome[1];
    break;
  case 30:
    // What to write?
    // P4.setText("std2"+readIncome[1] ); // CheckBox
    break;
  case 40:
    inputPULI.setLabel("Bullet - "+readIncome[1] );
    break;
  case 70:
    inputNapryzenieKV.setLabel("Voltage - "+readIncome[1] );
    break;
  case 60:
    Vin.setText("Voltage K.V - "+readIncome[1] );
    break;
  case 50:
    // What to write?
    // CheckBoxuvum.setText("UV/UM - "+readIncome[1] ); // RadioButton
    break;
  default:
    println("DisplayData(): no case selected.");
    break; // technically not necessary, but I like my switches tidy
  }
}
```

GUI:

```
int min1 = 0;
int PUL;
float NapryzenieKV;
boolean strata=false;

Button minutess;
ImageButton button; 
Numberbox inputPULI; 
Numberbox inputNapryzenieKV; 
RadioButton CheckBoxuvum; 
CheckBox P4; 
Textlabel Vin; 
Button connection; 
Button Send; 

public void setupUI()
{
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  PFont fontn = createFont("Times New Roman", 18);
  PFont p = createFont("Times New Roman", 18);
  ControlFont font=new
    ControlFont(p);
  cp5.setFont(font);

  connection = cp5.addButton("toplug")
    .setCaptionLabel("ПУСК")
    .setPosition(387, 30)
    .setSize(150, 30);

  serialPortsList = cp5.addDropdownList("Порт")
    .setPosition(130, 30)
    .setSize(150, 200)
    .setItemHeight(30)
    .setBarHeight(30);

  minutess = cp5.addButton("minutesss")
    .setCaptionLabel("ВЫКЛ")
    .setPosition(145, 100)
    .setSize(90, 25);

  Send = cp5.addButton("toapply")
    .setCaptionLabel("Apply")
    .setPosition(510, 370)
    .setSize(150, 30);

  Vin = cp5.addTextlabel("naprazhenie kondencatora")
    .setText("Voltage K.V")
    .setFont(p)
    .setColor(color(#00ffff))
    .setPosition(45, 320);

  CheckBoxuvum = cp5.addRadioButton("UV/UM")
    .setPosition(155, 360)
    .setSize(15, 15)
    .setColorActive(color(255))
    .setItemsPerRow(2)
    .setSpacingColumn(85)
    .addItem("+", 1)
    .addItem("-", 2);

  P4 = cp5.addCheckBox("std2")
    .setPosition(150, 190)
    .setSize(15, 15)
    .setItemsPerRow(1)
    .setSpacingColumn(30)
    .setSpacingRow(20)
    .addItem("Check", 2);

  inputPULI = cp5.addNumberbox("PUL")
    .setLabel("Bullet")
    .setPosition(150, 220)
    .setSize(80, 30)
    .setColorValue(0xffffff00)
    .setFont(p)
    .setScrollSensitivity(1.1)
    .setDirection(Controller.HORIZONTAL)
    .setRange(1, 199)
    .setValue(3);
  Label labelinputPULI = inputPULI.getCaptionLabel();
  labelinputPULI.setFont(font);
  labelinputPULI.setColor(color(#00ffff));
  labelinputPULI.toUpperCase(false);
  labelinputPULI.setText("Пуль");
  labelinputPULI.align(ControlP5.LEFT_OUTSIDE, CENTER);
  labelinputPULI.getStyle().setPaddingLeft(-55);

  inputNapryzenieKV = cp5.addNumberbox("NapryzenieKV")
    .setLabel("Voltage")
    .setPosition(150, 270)
    .setSize(80, 30)
    .setColorValue(0xffffff00)
    .setFont(p)
    .setScrollSensitivity(1.1)
    .setMin(25)
    .setMax(99)
    .setMultiplier(0.01)
    .setDirection(Controller.HORIZONTAL)
    .setValue(25);
  Label labelinputNapryzenieKV = inputNapryzenieKV.getCaptionLabel();
  labelinputNapryzenieKV.setFont(font);
  labelinputNapryzenieKV.setColor(color(#00ffff));
  labelinputNapryzenieKV.toUpperCase(false);
  labelinputNapryzenieKV.setText("Напряжение");
  labelinputNapryzenieKV.align(ControlP5.LEFT_OUTSIDE, CENTER);
  labelinputNapryzenieKV.getStyle().setPaddingLeft(-45);

  textFont(fontn);
  {
    // button dimensions
    int w = 99;
    int h = 25;
    // test with generated images
    button = new ImageButton(140, 140, w, h, 
      new PImage[]{
      getImage(w, h, color(192, 0, 32 * 2)), // off
      getImage(w, h, color(0, 0, 32 * 3)), // 10
      getImage(w, h, color(0, 0, 32 * 4)), // 20
      getImage(w, h, color(0, 0, 32 * 5)), // 30
      getImage(w, h, color(0, 0, 32 * 6)), // 40
      getImage(w, h, color(0, 0, 32 * 7)), // 50
      getImage(w, h, color(0, 0, 32 * 8)), // 60
      });
  }
}
void mousePressed() {
  button.mousePressed(mouseX, mouseY);
  println(button.min);
}
// test images to represent loaded state images
PImage getImage(int w, int h, int c) {
  PImage img = createImage(w, h, RGB);
  java.util.Arrays.fill(img.pixels, c);
  img.updatePixels();
  return img;
}

// make a custom image button class
class ImageButton {
  // minutes is the data it stores
  int min = 0;
  // images for each state
  PImage[] stateImages;
  // which image to display
  int stateIndex;
  // position
  int x, y;
  // dimensions: width , height
  int w, h;
  // text to display
  String label = "ВЫКЛ";

  ImageButton(int x, int y, int w, int h, PImage[] stateImages) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.stateImages = stateImages;
  }
  void mousePressed(int mx, int my) {
    // check the cursor is within the button bounds
    boolean isOver = ((mx >= x && mx <= x + w) && // check horizontal
      (my >= y && my <= y + h) ); // check vertical

    if (isOver) {

      min += 10;
      stateIndex++;

      if (min>60) {
        min = 0; 
        stateIndex = 0;
        label = "ВЫКЛ";
      } else {
        label = (str(min) + "Мин");
      }
    }
  }
  void draw() {
    // if the images and index are valid
    if (stateImages != null && stateIndex < stateImages.length) {
      image(stateImages[stateIndex], x, y, w, h);
    } else {
      println("error displaying button state image");
      println("stateImages: ");
      printArray(stateImages);
      println("stateIndex: " + stateIndex);
    }
    // display text
    text(label, x + 17, y + h - 8);
  }
}
public void minutesss() {

  min1 += 10;
  if (min1>60) {
    min1 = 0; 
    minutess.setCaptionLabel("ВЫКЛ");
  } else { 
    minutess.setCaptionLabel(str(min1)+" Мин1");
  }
}
void controlEvent(ControlEvent theEvent) {
  if (theEvent.isFrom(CheckBoxuvum)) {
    //myColorBackground = 0;
    print("got an event from "+CheckBoxuvum.getName()+"\t\n");
    // checkbox uses arrayValue to store the state of 
    // individual checkbox-items. usage:
    println(CheckBoxuvum.getArrayValue());
    int col = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<CheckBoxuvum.getArrayValue().length; i++) {
      int n = (int)CheckBoxuvum.getArrayValue()[i];
      print(n);
      if (n==1) {
        //myColorBackground += CheckBoxuvum.getItem(i).internalValue();
      }
    }
    println();
  }

  if (theEvent.isGroup()) {
    // check if the Event was triggered from a ControlGroup
    println("event from group : "+theEvent.getGroup().getValue()+" from "+theEvent.getGroup());
  } else if (theEvent.isController()) {
    println("event from controller : "+theEvent.getController().getValue()+" from "+theEvent.getController());
  }
}
```

Protocol:

```
int lengthmas = 7;
int RC = -128; // -128 separating byte в java.
int[] readIncome = new int[lengthmas];
int[] writeOutgioing = new int[lengthmas];
String incomingData= null;
String outgoingData=null;

void readInc() {
  while ( serialPort.available() > 0) {
    incomingData = serialPort.readStringUntil(RC);
    readIncome = int(split (incomingData, ',' )); // the received data is comma separated.
  }
}

void  writeOut() {
  outgoingData=str(writeOutgioing[0])+str(writeOutgioing[1])+str(writeOutgioing[2])+str(writeOutgioing[3])+str(writeOutgioing[4])+str(writeOutgioing[5])+str(writeOutgioing[6]); // sending data as a string.
  serialPort.write(outgoingData);
}

/*Protocol:
 Protocol composition - an array of seven elements, 0 - command, 1-4 data, 5 - remainder of packets for transmission,  6 (-128) separating byte.
 The controller responds by sending the same command and data.
 Example: 10(Command),235,2353,564,5(packages left),77777(CRC),-128(RC)
 Commands:
 Modifier:
 10 - minutess = cp5.addButton
 20 - ImageButton button
 30 - CheckBox P4
 40 - Numberbox inputPULI
 70 - Numberbox inputNapryzenieKV
 60 - Textlabel Vin
 50 - RadioButton CheckBoxuvum
 */
```

Senddata:

```
public void toapply()
{
}
```

loop:

```
void draw() {
  background(50);
  button.draw();
}
{
  if (strata) {
    readInc();
    //readIncome[]
    Displaydata();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a compiler error or exception? Could you please describe what is happening. And do not include images of code in your question.

Comment: So, what is your question? What do you need help with? Hint: at least at the start, for debugging purposes, use a text-based protocol, so that you can use any serial console to debug with.

Comment: Your switch statement should have a default so that you can easily detect bad commands.

Comment: Ok, something doesn't work, but what's happening? Nothing, a crash, an error message? Please explain how you know that your code has something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `default:`.

The switch run like this: it finds the case which corresponds to the key and starts executing code from this point on until it hits a `break;`. The `default:` case is a catch-all: it'll like a condition which would always be true.

To illustrate, I like this example: here when the user enters a number, it prints to the console the names of all the month from that point up to December.

```
int month = 5;

switch (month) {
    case 1:  println("January");
    case 2:  println("February");
    case 3:  println("March");
    case 4:  println("April");
    case 5:  println("May");
    case 6:  println("June");
    case 7:  println("July");
    case 8:  println("August");
    case 9:  println("September");
    case 10: println("October");
    case 11: println("November");
    case 12: println("December");
             break;
    default: println("Error: no valid month selected.");
             break;
}
```

Notice how `default` is at the end. That's because since it's always "true" and since the switch will select only one case and then run until a `break` statement, if I put it anywhere else it will always be selected when it's read. See by modifying the example like this:

```
int month = 5;

switch (month) {
    default: println("Whatever, I'm not printing month anymore!");
             break; // no case after this point will ever be read
    case 1:  println("January");
    case 2:  println("February");
    case 3:  println("March");
    case 4:  println("April");
    case 5:  println("May");
    case 6:  println("June");
    case 7:  println("July");
    case 8:  println("August");
    case 9:  println("September");
    case 10: println("October");
    case 11: println("November");
    case 12: println("December");
             break;
}
```

This is exactly what happens in your program. In `DisplayData()`, right at tthe beginning there's a `default` case which overrides all the other cases:

```
void Displaydata() {

  switch(readIncome[0]) {
  case 10:
  default: // <--- HERE THIS IS ALWAYS SELECTED
    minutess.setCaptionLabel(readIncome[1]+" Мин.");
    min=readIncome[1];
    break; // <--- EVERYTHING AFTER THIS IS IGNORED
```

You can re-write with the correct syntax like this:

```
void Displaydata() {
  switch(readIncome[0]) {
  case 10:
    minutess.setCaptionLabel(readIncome[1]+" Мин.");
    min=readIncome[1];
    break;
  case 20:
    button.label(readIncome[1]+" Мин."); //ImageButton
    min=readIncome[1];
    break;
  case 30:
    if(readIncome[1]==1)P4.setText("on");
    if(readIncome[1]==0)P4.setText("off");// CheckBox
    break;
  case 40:
    inputPULI.setText("Bullet - "+readIncome[1] ); //Numberbox int
    break;
  case 70:
    inputNapryzenieKV.setText("Voltage - "+readIncome[1] ); //Numberbox float
    break;
  case 60:
    Vin.setText("Voltage K.V - "+readIncome[1] );
    break;
  case 50:
    if(readIncome[1]==1)CheckBoxuvum.setText("+"); //RadioButton
    if(readIncome[1]==0)CheckBoxuvum.setText("-");
    break;
  default:
    println("DisplayData(): no case selected.");
    break; // technically not necessary, but I like my switches tidy
  }
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: It's too early to rejoice, probably the wrong question was asked in the topic. Pay attention to the screenshot, the error is below (The "setText (String)" function is not defined. How to fix it for variables?
ImageButton button;
Numberbox inputPULI;
Numberbox inputNapryzenieKV;
RadioButton CheckBoxuvum;
CheckBox P4;
See the GUI file!

Comment: `CheckBoxuvum;` is a `RadioButton` as seen in it's declaration. [It doesn't have a `.setText()` method](http://www.sojamo.com/libraries/controlP5/reference/controlP5/CheckBox.html). Instead use one of it's label methods, `setLabel()` or `.setCaptionLabel()` (experiment, I don't know which one is the right one, probably the first).

Comment: Don't know how to write for ImageButton button too? Similar to Button minutess.

Comment: [Documentation mention the existence of `.setLabel()`](http://www.sojamo.com/libraries/controlP5/reference/controlP5/Controller.html#setLabel-java.lang.String-). I didn't mess around a lot with controlP5, so I'm just throwing you the obvious stuff from the documentation right now. NumberBox has `.setLabel()` too.